# ¿Como eliminar elementos de un array con Jquery o Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

En un evento click voy añadiendo elementos de la siguiente forma:

```
var aprobaciones = [];
var contador_id=0;
$('#btn_agrega_elementos').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            contador_id=contador_id+1;
            var id = contador_id;
            var a = $("#primero").val();
            var b = $("#segundo").val();

                var presupuesto = {
                    id: id,
                    primero: a,
                    segundo:b
                }
                aprobaciones.push(presupuesto);
});
```

Estos elementos los voy añadiendo a la fila de un datatable, y lo que deseo, es que debo darle la opción de eliminar la fila. Pero mi pregunta es, como puedo eliminar los elementos de una fila, por ejemplo como elimino toda la fila o elementos que tienen el id=2.?

Espero poder haberme explicado bien, desde ya, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con vanilla javascript lo puedes lograr utilizando el metodo `findIndex`(Puedes ver que este metodo es soportado por el 99% de los navegadores [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/findIndex) ).

Con este metodo buscaremos el indice de tu `id` y posteriormente lo eliminaremos del arreglo utilizando el metodo `splice` el cual recibe 2 parametros, primero el indice a eliminar, segundo la cantidad de elementos a eliminar.

```js
var aprobaciones = [];
aprobaciones.push({
    id: 1,
    primero: '1',
    segundo: '1'
})
aprobaciones.push({
    id: 2,
    primero: '2',
    segundo: '2'
})
aprobaciones.push({
    id: 3,
    primero: '3',
    segundo: '3'
})

//Todos los items
console.log(aprobaciones)
let indexForDelete = aprobaciones.findIndex(aprobacion => aprobacion.id === 2);

//Eliminando item
aprobaciones.splice(indexForDelete, 1);
console.log(aprobaciones)
```

El metodo `findIndex` aprovecha el poder de las funciones de flechas para tener una sentencia corta y clara. Como es una sola instrucción no requiere de la palabra reservada `return` si se encuentra un item con el `id 2`, retornara el indice en el `array`.

Comment: Excelente @Albert Hidalgo, consulta, el valor 1 que le envias como parametro, que quiere decir a aprobaciones.splice(indexForDelete, 1);?

Comment: Como te comente en la respuesta, el segundo parámetro osea el `1` es la cantidad de elementos que deseas eliminar a partir de la posición que pasas como primer parámetro.

Comment: o sea en este caso, como tenemos el id,primero y segundo, el parametro debería ser 3.
aprobaciones.splice(indexForDelete, 3);
???

Comment: @Danilo fíjate bien la explicación de la respuesta. Se obtiene el indice, posterior se envía al método splice para borrar un único elemento.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Albert hidalgo, quisiera aprovechar de hacer otra pregunta. Si  quisiera editar el valor de un elemento, por ejemplo el valor primero que tiene el id=2, como lo haría?

Comment: La => me dice error de sintaxis.